# How to restore Default Domain Policy?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2019

I accidentally deleted "Default Domain Policy" in

> Group Policy Management -> Forest: mydomain -> Domain -> mydomain

Actually I clicking Delete Link(s) thinking that only the link will be deleted; The policy itself wouldn't.

I tried:

- dcgpofix /target:both
- ADUC -> Domain_name.com -> Property -> Switch to Group Policy tab -> Create a policy named "Default Domain Policy" (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/556025/how-to-manually-create-default-domain-gpo). In this case I didn't have Group Policy tab.

How to restore deleted Default Domain Policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really deleted the default domain policy: you only **unlinked** it from the domain. The fix is very simple:

- open the group policy management console
- right-click on your domain
- select "link an existing GPO"
- select the right policy and click "OK"